# I don't know how to explain but when i execute something in character it had appeared in numerical

Tags: c++

i am new here. I need your help.
I am executing a simple program. To print some word. But after executing numerical were appearing on the screen.I was hoping for the alphabets.

here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char a='K';
char h='P';
char text='L';
char text1='T';
int result='?';
result=a+text+h+text1;
cout<<result;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're just adding integers together, which results in another integer. What you seem to want is to *append strings* together.

Comment: Are you seriously thinking that `int` can hold some word?

Comment: `int result='?'; result=a+text+h+text1` what did you expect that to do? if the answer is form a *string*, that's not how you do that in C++.

Comment: In computers, characters like `'K'` and `'P'` are stored (encoded) as numbers.

Answer (score 2):

`char` holds character code (integer) of characters and adding that will result in integers.

Here are some choice:

You can use [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) to concatenate characters to a string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char a='K';
    char h='P';
    char text='L';
    char text1='T';
    stringstream result;
    result << a << text << h << text1;
    cout<<result.str();
    return 0;
}
```

You can print the characters directly:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char a='K';
    char h='P';
    char text='L';
    char text1='T';
    cout<< a << text << h << text1;
    return 0;
}
```

You can use initializer list to build a string from characters (since C++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char a='K';
    char h='P';
    char text='L';
    char text1='T';
    string result{a, text, h, text1};
    cout<<result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a possible fourth solution as well: Use strings instead of characters, and concatenate using `+`.